# Chrome Link Bug: Removing # and everything after when coming from external app

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, single-page-application

There is a massive bug I believe I just found in Chrome that is really messing up a lot of our SPA.

We send emails to clients that link back to our site, with a url structure like:

mydomain.com/#/category/page

I just found that as of today (it may have happened earlier) - that anytime we open one of those links from an email (specifically tested in outlook and thunderbird) Chrome AUTOMATICALLY removes the # and everything there after.

So chrome is taking mydomain.com/#/category/page and removing the #/... leaving the user at mydomain.com

I've tested IE and Firefox and they retain the # and everything after. It appears only chrome is removing it.

This is causing massive problems as we have a huge amount of outgoing emails w/ these links.

Has anyone else experienced this? i'm trying avoid going through and changing ALL links and removing the # but i'm not finding any other solution.

Also.. this must have been implemented in a very recent update to Chrome as these links have been working for over a year for us. I just received an email from a customer today which led me to find it... however I can't imagine it would have been in place for much longer than a day or so as we would have been notified pretty quickly.